# I need a code to write characteristics in BLE through bluetoothGattCallback in android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, device

I am working in a project where a BLE device gets unlocked after I write a particular String into the characteristics. My device is getting connected, the state of connection is working. The debugger even coming to onServicesDiscovered() method. But it is not writing the characteristics I guess, cause it is not unlocking the device. The device is absolutely fine because i have tested it with successful unlocking by creating a flutter app through pauldemarco's FlutterBlue. Can anyone provide me with an android code for kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Already figured it out.

I failed to pass the service UUID and the Characteristics UUID and the descriptor UUID as well.